# Angular Unit Test Error: 1 component threw errors during cleanup at TestBedRender3.destroyActiveFixtures

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm testing a component which has injected a service. The problem that as I saw, it's not entering the ngOnDestroy(). I ask explicity the test to destroy() after every test I get error message that "cannot unsubscribe from undefined". What could be the problem?

Component:

```
//...
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private readonly router: Router,
                private dialog: MatDialog,
                private readonly carService: carService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.cars$ = this.carService.getCars();
        this.subscription= this.cars$.subscribe(cars=> {
            this.cars= cars;
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Test:

```
//...
  beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({

            providers: [
                {provide: MatDialog, useClass: dialogMock},
                {provide: Router, useValue: routerMock},
                {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/cars'}
            ]
        }).compileComponents();

        component = TestBed.createComponent(CarComponent).componentInstance;
        service = TestBed.inject(CarService);
        service.setProjects([firstCar, secondCar]);
        component.ngOnInit();
    });

    it('test', () => {
        expect(component).toBeInstanceOf(CarComponent);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `ngOnInit` is not ran before `ngOnDestroy` is ran.

How are you mocking `carService` and `getCars`? You need to be mocking this service and `getCars` method. Check this out on how to mock a component depending on services: https://testing-angular.com/testing-components-depending-on-services/#testing-components-depending-on-services.

For a quick unblock, you can change the `ngOnDestroy` to this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

If the subscription exists, then we unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ngOnInit changes the state of cars in your
Typescript file and you did not tell your test to pick up on the change.
So instead of putting in:

```
    component.ngOnInit();
```

You should in it's place put in:

```
   let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CarComponent);
   fixture.detectChanges();
```

That way when the program naturally changes the value in cars your test file will pick up on it, and you won't have to worry about conditionally destroying the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an issue with a missing provider.
The `ngOnDestroy` invoked a function of a service that was not provided in the test configuration.

Once I provided the service in the test configuration the error went away.